# Player targeted by Executive Order card must obey the other player order?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

The Executive Order card says:

> **Action:** Choose any other player. He may move his character and then take 1 action OR not move and take 2 actions.

This does not state that the player targeted by the Executive Order should do what the player who played the card order (or even if he *can* order something). So, this is the question: When someone use the Executive Order, he can order other player to do something or the card just let the other player do whatever he wants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try giving orders, but the other player is in full control of the actions.

For this reason, never XO the person to your left unless all Cylons have been positively identified.  Giving a Cylon 3 actions in a row is very hard to overcome!

Comment: Correct. In fact a great way to get people to play XOs on you when you're a Cylon is to happily agree to do the suggested order. Then you do something bad with your first action, and reveal with your second!

(Or if your turn is next, then you perform two bad things and THEN reveal on your turn!)